# How to let the hackerrank read the local .csv file?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am coding on the hackkerrank. The code ran well on my computer but when it turned to the hackerrank, it showed that the `.csv` file didn't exist! So what's the problem? Anyone helps me please! Here is my code.

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/dell/Data/1.csv',
               names = ['charge_time','battery_time'])
```

Comment: Sorry you can't read local files unless your program is in your local disk

Comment: Thanks! I've got it !

Answer (score 1):

The path in your `read_csv` function is a local path, therefore the script must be executed locally in order to find the file.
If you execute your script from a remote machine, make sure the csv file is in the same machine and modify its path in the `read_csv` function so it matches the path inside the remote machine.

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'the_path_in_the_remote_machine/1.csv',
           names = ['charge_time','battery_time'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got it !

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to upvote and mark as resolved :)